# Pandas convert a DataFrame [monthly data] with index 0 1 2 ... to a specific date Year-month range

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a panda DataFrame which is of size 365,1 
Data is based by month.
The current index is 0 1 2 ...
I want to convert the current index to a Year Month format where the first month is 1987 January. 
So the index 0 should by replace by 1978 January , the index 1 by 1987 February etc.

I have tired

```
pd.to_datetime(df, unit='m', origin=pd.Timestamp('1987-01-01'))
```

But I must have done something wrong as it gives me the error

```
 unit='m' not valid with non-numerical val='[8940982.93]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with `DateOffset`

```
s=df.index.map(lambda x : pd.DateOffset(months=x) + pd.to_datetime('1978-01-01'))
s.strftime('%Y-%B')
Index(['1978-January', '1978-February', '1978-March', '1978-April', '1978-May',
       '1978-June', '1978-July', '1978-August', '1978-September',
       '1978-October'],
      dtype='object')
```